# C++: How do I pass a pointer to a member function of another class?

Tags: c++, callback, function-pointers, boost-function

How would the signature for function `Foo()` fo class `classA` have to look when I want to pass a pointer to a function that is a member of `classB`?
Function `update()` is called on an isntance of `classB` and gets passed an object of `classA`. Inside `update()` the function `Foo()` of `classA` shall be passed a pointer to a callback function. That function is a member of `classB`.
I can't make anything static here. Is there a way to do this, maybe with `boost::function` ?

**Code:**

```
class classA
{
 public:
  voif Foo(/*a pointer to a memberfunction of ClassB*/)
};

class classB
{
 classB(){nVal = 0;}
 int nVal;
 public:
 void increment(int n){nVal += n;}
 void update(classA objA)
 {
  objA.Foo(increment)
 }
};
```

Comment: Use inheritance and virtual functions. That's why this mechanism is there for.

Comment: You might want to read about [`std::function`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function) and [`std::bind`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/bind).

Comment: @JoachimPileborg: Thank you. I wasn't aware of std::function and std::bind.

Comment: @barakmanos: In the above case, how exactly is inheritance gonna help, when types `classA` and `classB` are clearly distinct and `Foo()` in `classA` is merely taking a ref to some callable?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `boost::bind` with `boost::function`.

```
class classA
{
public:
   void Foo(const boost::function<void(int)>& function)
   {
   }
};

class classB
{
public:
   //
   void update(classA objA)
   {
       objA.Foo(boost::bind(&classB::increment, this, _1));
   }
};
```